# How to select all elements of type="submit" with jQuery to disable them

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have several forms and I am using one function from which I get the elements and submit it.
Sometimes, I use a button element and sometimes I use an input type="submit" element.

```js
function myFun(ele) {
  var jEle = $(ele);
  var form = $(ele).closest("form");
  var button = jEle;
  $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false); // To disable Submit Button
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="myFun(this)">
  <input type="text" value="Example">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

How can I select and disable any element with type="submit"?

Answer (score 3):

You could use both button and input in the jQuery selector in any way you like of these:
`':submit'`
`'[type="submit"]'`
`'input[type="submit"], button[type="submit"]'`

```js
function myFun(ele) {
  event.preventDefault()
  var jEle = $(ele);
  var form = $(ele).closest("form");
  var button = jEle;
  $('[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true); // To disable Submit Button
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="myFun(this.event)">
  <input type="text" value="Example">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass Sorry if my post grab your credit Orz... I just found out that I'm able to do comment already ! Previously due to my low reputation and I can't make a comment here, that's why I use the 'answer' method. Really really sorry deeply from my heart ! _/|\_

Comment: It's fine, just enjoy life! :) I'm thinking about anyone visiting this in the future. Care less about credit.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness! I believe your answer already covers all posible ways of getting the 'submit' element. It will come in handy for someone in the future! Happy coding :)